# How to get Rails to autoload an array class used in Ruby Open classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm assuming there's a best practice for this that I'm just missing. I've got an array class in a utils directory I created, where I've added custom array methods, like so:

```
# app/utils/array.rb

class Array
  def my_method
  end
end
```

However, when I run rails, it skips autoloading my array class because array is obviously already loaded. If I require_relative the array file in whatever file I need, I'm able to use the methods. I know that's not the best way to do that, so I'm wondering what the best practices are for using open classes without throwing off rails autoloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're using Rails 6, that mean Rails use [zeitwerk](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk) behind the scenes. In that case, Rails will automatically auto-load all code in '/app' folder but it'll ignore any `class` that already loaded. So in your case, since Rails already load Ruby core class `Array` before, it'll ignore your `Array` extension.

You can create an initializers to load your extensions of ruby core classes

```
# config/initializers/core_ext.rb
Dir[File.join(Rails.root, "app", "utils", "*.rb")].each {|ext| require ext}
```

Notice that the above code will override load-path of each *.rb in your 'utils' folder if the class is not loaded, and it'll make confusion (and error prone) about those classes that's not an extension of Ruby core classes. For example, your code already has Foo class

```
# app/service/foo.rb
class Foo
  def hello
  end
end
```

now you extend it in `utils`

```
class Foo
  def test
  end
end
```

After create above initializer, the utils/foo is the only class will be loaded:

```
> rails c
> Foo.new.hello # NoMethodError
```

It's also little sense to create new extension of Foo in your 'utils' instead of modify foo.rb (or create modules), right ? And nobody know which foo is loaded first (until they read the initializer code).

Beside that, your folder named 'utils', it's not clear about the `extension` purpose.

In my opinion, the best practice is that you separate all your extensions of Ruby core classes or libs's classes into another folder and it's better to move them into 'lib/extensions'. Other 'utils' classes should move to 'helpers' or 'concerns' according Rails style.

Comment: Awesome, this is what I was looking for. Thanks